# jQuery AJAX upload progress for large text fields

Tags: jquery, forms, progress

Is it possible to get the upload-progress for a form with very large textfields using jQuery ajax?
I think the client knows how much bytes have been sent, but when I Google I only find solutions for file-uploads using server-site code.

This is my ajax-request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?action=saveNewPost",
        data: {textbox1: textbox1,textbox2: textbox2},
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(){
            //
        }
    });
```

I was hoping there would be something like "onProgress" with a parameter containing the amount of bytes already sent...

**Found a solution**

```
$.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var req = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (req) {
                req.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                        $('#ajaxFeedbackDiv').html(event.loaded); // = 'test'; //event.loaded + ' / ' + event.total;
                    }
                }, false);
            }
            return req;
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?action=saveNewPost",
        data: {textbox1: textbox1,textbox2: textbox2},
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
        }
    });
```

this seems to work, altough there are still

**2 problems:**

1. the connection on my localhost is way too fast, so it's hard to see the "progress" actually working. I installed this tool http://mschrag.github.com on a second Mac in the same network and I see that it's working perfectly.
2. I'm not sure if this will fall-back friendly on non-XHR/HTML5-compatible browsers, i.e. just upload without progress information?

Comment: Actually there's really a `onprogress` callback in the `XMLHttpRequest` object. However, it's a new standard and not all browsers supports that.

Comment: please see what I've added above, it works. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this with the new [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) object in HTML5 capable browsers. It supports the `progress` event that you could subscribe to and be notified of the AJAX operation.

Here's an example:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var percentage = Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
            document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = percentage + '%';
        }
    }, false);

    xhr.open(this.method, this.action, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.send(new FormData(this));
    return false;    
};
```

and here's a [`live demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/cGQBM/2/).

Comment: thank you very much, but that would mean this would only work with HTML5-capable browsers and I can not use jQuery AJAX anymore? I should at least have a friendly fallback (i.e. not showing progress) on incompatible browsers...

Comment: I see in the jQuery documentation that a jQuery-AJAX-request returns an xhr-object, I tried using that with your progress-eventlistener, but it doesn't work...

Comment: do you know if it would be possible to use the jQuery ajax and its returned jqXHR-object?

Comment: please see what I've added above, it works. Thanks for your support

Comment: You are still relying on the new `XMLHttpRequest` method and more specifically on the `progress` event. Your code won't work in browsers that do not support it.

Comment: how can I detect non-XHR/progress-event-capable browsers? Then I could exclude that part of the code for them, right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this jquery plugin:

https://www.articlage.com/adrianillo/article/DataUploader

Just  add a progressbar to upload process