# Check browsers capability of XHR and progress-event

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Following this question:

[jQuery AJAX upload progress for large text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717146/jquery-ajax-upload-progress-for-large-text-fields)

how can I make it compatible for older browsers?

As you can see in the question above, I am relying on XHR and the progress-event. Now for older browsers, I need to detect if they are not capable of one of these so I can skip the progress-bar and still make my AJAX-post.

I thought it could work like this:

```
$.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (xhr instanceof window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                        progressPercent = Math.round(event.loaded/event.total*100)+'%';
                        $loader.width(progressPercent);
                    }
                }, false);
            }else{
                alert('XHR is no instance of window.XMLHttpRequest');
            }
            return xhr;
        },
        type: "POST",
...
```

but I don't know if that's save or if there's anything else I'd have to check.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something close to total safety, you could use a try/catch/finally structure :

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        try {
            xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    $loader.width(Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100) + '%');
                }
            }, false);
        }
        catch(err) {
            //Progess not available
            //Take appropriate action - eg hide the progress thermometer
            $loader.hide();
        }
        finally {
            return xhr;
        }
    },
    type: "POST",
    ...
}):
```

Comment: thank you! I'll try that one out. My "problem" is that all my browsers are modern and capable of xhr & progress, so I can only investigate when I'm at my day-job with out-dated browsers ;)