# Percentage progress of an Ajax request with Transfer-Encoding: Chunked

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

I want to know if it's possible to get the percentage status of an Ajax GET request (using jQuery) in conditions that the header has no specified Content-Length.

I'm using Transfer-Encoding: Chunked instead of Content-Length.

Comment: How could you calculate a percentage if you don't know the total?

Comment: The length using Transfer-Encoding: Chunked are sent right before the chunk itself..

Answer (score 4):

No, it is impossible. Chunked transfer-encoding allows to send data **without** knowing the size of the content. Your client cannot calculate the percentage as it does not know the total length.

If you want to watch the progress of the request, you can do that [as shown in another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16633258/2948765). [Here](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/) is another example for up- and downloading. However, this is a relatively new feature and not supported in all browsers.

Comment: Well, I create a custom header rule where I calculate the content of the sent data. I'm using this plugin https://github.com/kpozin/jquery-ajaxprogress, can you give me an advice what should I need to modify to work with my custom header rule instead of Content-Type?

Comment: Anyone can tell me how to get the current number of the bytes transfered between client and server in a HTTP request made using Ajax?

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. I don't upload files, I just make a GET ajax request.

Comment: @user1392136 [The second link](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/) provides an example of getting the progress of up- and downloading.